# Unity - Custom Editor of List don't show properties but a gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I went into an issue while creating a custom editor and using a List of a custom class.

I had the following script for the classes:

customClass.cs

```
[System.Serializable]
public class customClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int test;
}
```

classToEdit.cs

```
public class classToEdit : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private List<customClass> customClassList;
}
```

I had this script for the editor class:

classToEditEditor.cs

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(classToEdit))]
public class classToEditEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // Update the serialize object
        serializedObject.Update();

        // Display properties
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("customClassList"), true);

        // Apply modif
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

And when I go to the inspector, I have the following:
[image]

Fact is I don't want to drag and drop something, I want to set my complete object here.

Below is the solution for the future me and you !

Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple: Just remove the MonoBehaviour class from whiwh derive your custom object. This is automatically added by Unity but remove it.

So, you customClass.cs is now like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class customClass
{
    public int test;
}
```

By doing that, you'll have the following:
[image]

Few tips when creating a custom editor:

- Don't forget to remove the MonoBehaviour class when using a List of your custom class
- Don't forget to add System.Serializable before your custom class
- In your editor, don't forget to set the includeChildren at true in the EditorGUILayout.PropertyField method